# Passing a byte array from JNI directly in Android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface

I have a grayscale image as a byte array in JNI, and I need to pass it to Android to be displayed on screen. At the moment my code is as follows: I copy the byte array to an int array in JNI, and then I set the pixels of the Bitmap with that array:

JNI side:

```
jintArray frame = g_env->NewIntArray(frameSize);
int tempFrame[frameSize];
for(int pix = 0; pix < frameSize; pix++){
    //convert every byte to int
    jint greyValue = 0xff000000 | (( byteArray[pix] << 16) & 0xffff0000) | ((byteArray[pix] << 8) & 0xff00ff00) | (byteArray[pix] & 0xff0000ff);
    tempFrame[pix] = greyValue;
}
g_env->SetIntArrayRegion(frame, 0, frameSize, tempFrame);

//return the array setting a variable in java
g_env->SetObjectField(g_o, g_env->GetFieldID(g_class, "mFrame", "[I"), frame);
```

then, Java side:

```
//Somewhere in SurfaceView.surfaceCreated method
if(mBitmap == null)
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageWidth, mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

//Somewhere in View.onDraw method
if(mBitmap != null && nativeClass.mFrame != null){
    mBitmap.setPixels(nativeClass.mFrame, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

    //Do some operations on the bitmap with mBitmap.setPixel()

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, null);
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to speedup the process, avoiding to copy the arrays two times (first from jintArray to int[] and then fromo int[] to Bitmap), for example by writing directly in the Bitmap, or by creating a Bitmap in JNI and passing it to Android.
(I know that canvas has a drawBitmap method that accepts int[] instead of Bitmap, but that method does not accept Rects for rescaling, so it is not feasible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way:

Create bitmap in Java code. 
Pass bitmap ref in native code. 
Use `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` to get pixel values array. 
Fill the array with data. 
Call `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels` at the end.

[Hard way.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/hNapviH05Xk/jDPaxsIgodEJ)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot... I receive the image from another thread using a callback function. ...Still, I could init the bitmap ref in some other function, so I will try that.
I'm not convinced with the hard way, I seem to recall that calling a java method from jni is computationally expensive, but I'll check on that too.

Comment: PS: I did as in the easy way, and it correctly works; thought it gives my some problems with the reference table... but this is a different issue, so I will open another question for that.